# Can't manage to connect with Windbg

Tags: kernel, windbg, windows-kernel

I followed this tuto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection-automatically to launch a kernel debug, but when I launch my debug sessions with

`windbg -k -d net:port=<YourDebugPort>,key=<YourKey>`

but even after restart my target computer nothing happen :( I don't have any errors so I don't really know how begin my researches... So if you have any advices or ideas I take them! :)

Edit :
This are the outpouts of `dbgsetting` in `bcdedit /enum all`

> identificateur          {dbgsettings} key
> KGG2CNLVNTOG.182LNPYIWWEM.1R9RI939CTH.ZPMN9LGVP83D debugtype
> NET hostip                  192.168.x.x port                    50317
> dhcp                    No

and this is the oupout of kdnet in the target machine

> Network debugging is supported on the following NICs: busparams=1.0.0,
> Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller, Not plugged in.
>
> Network debugging is supported on the following USB controllers:
> busparams=0.20.0, Contr¶leur h¶te Intel(R) USBá3.1 eXtensibleá-á1.10
> (Microsoft)
>
> KDNET transport initialization failed during a previous boot.  Status
> = 0xC0000001. No valid link. The network cable might not be properly connected.

Comment: What's your configuration? a host and a VM, two VMs, two physical machines? If using VMs which hypervisor? Can you post the `dbgsettings` part in the output of `bcdedit /enum all`? Can you show us the output of `kdnet.exe` on the debuggee machine? Can you ping (both ways) between the debugger machine and the debuggee? Have you tried with the firewall disabled?

Comment: Hi Neitsa! So i try to connect a Windows 11 physical machine and a Windows 10 physical machine,  and i can ping both machine and  i also tried without firewall! you can see the output in my previous messages now!

Comment: Does the error message from kdnet.exe repeats (even after a reboot for example)? It seems the kdnet transport (that is, the driver that is used to make the debugger and debugge communicate on the network) finds a valid NIC but sees it has disconnected somehow... You could maybe pass the `buparams` to [bcdedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--dbgsettings) (grep for "busparams").

Comment: I am sorry but i think i didn't totally understand what you want me to do :/

Comment: 1/2 For an unknown reason kdnet.exe does see your NIC (network card) but thinks it is unplugged (`Not plugged in` and then `The network cable might not be properly connected`).  Does this error message appears each time you try kdnet.exe (even after a reboot) ?

Comment: 2/2 In case you still see this error message, you may pass the `busparams` option to [bcdedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--dbgsettings); the busparams is given in the kdnet.exe output (see link to bcdedit in this message and search in the page for `busparams` on how to pass it to bcdedit.